# Using ACF Custom Field value in a URL with do_shortcode()

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, urls, advanced-custom-fields, variables

I am using the [ACF custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and [video.js](https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) plugins and I want to add the custom field value inside the url for the youtube video that is inside of `do_shortcode()`

So far this is what I've come up with but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php 
    $thevideo = the_field('video');
    echo do_shortcode('[videojs class="youtubevideo" youtube="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $thevideo . '"]'); 
?>
```

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom fields? Its `the_field()` function outputs variable to the browser, so `$thevideo` will be empty. You have to use `get_field()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need to replace  `the_field('video')` with `get_field('video')`.

**Why?**

Because according to ACF documentation;

[`get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value)`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

> Returns the value of the specified field.

Whereas on the other hand

[`the_field($field_name, $post_id)`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

> Displays the value of the specified field. (this is the same as “echo get_field($field_name)”)

Hope this might help others as well.